# I have two lists, I want to generate a result similar to the picture, how should I use pandas to do it？

Tags: python-3.x

```
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd

Forecast_price = [1,2,3,4,5]
Forecast_R = [a,b,c]
```

[Looking at this picture, I want to achieve such an effect!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoSll.png)

How can we generate a data format like the following table? Thanks!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide the
[shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
also make sure to provide some input and the corresponding desired output. also: [images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) are not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import itertools

Forecast_price = [1,2,3,4,5]
Forecast_R = ['a','b','c']

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=list(zip(
        itertools.cycle(Forecast_price),
        itertools.chain(*(itertools.repeat(x, len(Forecast_price)) for x in Forecast_R)),
    )),
    columns=['col1', 'col2']
)

    col1 col2
0      1    a
1      2    a
2      3    a
3      4    a
4      5    a
5      1    b
6      2    b
7      3    b
8      4    b
9      5    b
10     1    c
11     2    c
12     3    c
13     4    c
14     5    c
```

If you want the first column as index:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=list(itertools.chain(*itertools.repeat(Forecast_price, len(Forecast_R)))),
    data=list(itertools.chain(*(itertools.repeat(x, len(Forecast_price)) for x in Forecast_R))),
    columns=['col1']
)

  col1
1    a
2    a
3    a
4    a
5    a
1    b
2    b
3    b
4    b
5    b
1    c
2    c
3    c
4    c
5    c
```